# How to restrict Redshift user/group to a single database in multiple databases in a single cluster environment

Tags: amazon-redshift

How can we restrict Redshift user/group to a single database in multiple databases in a single cluster environment.

For example the user **test1_user** is in **test1_group1** created in a database called **test1_DB** and later we created another database **test2_DB** and when we query in **test2_DB** the **pg_group** or **pg_use**r tables,we can see **test1_user** and **test1_group**.

Answer (score -1):

The ability to access databases and database objects (tables and views) within a redshift cluster is controlled by user/group accounts. As you have mentioned that you are trying to control database access you need to review your user account permissions. You can manage and create these using the create user/group and grant/revoke statements.

The easiest way might be to execute a revoke statement using your super user account and revoke access to test1_user/group for test2_DB. 
e.g.

```
revoke all on all tables in test2_db from test1_group1
```

Somethings to check might be who created the database object. By default whoever created the database object is the owner. So if your test1_group1 created the new DB you should go back and create it with your superuser account.

Comment: Thats fine,i know the tables and schemas from test2_db and i dont grant anything on those tables in test1_db,so my only concern is why i'm allowed to see the access details(pg_user and pg_group) of the test1_db groups and users in test2_db.May be because common sharing of system tables across multiple databases.Any super user(not root) in a database can see all the access control details in all the databases in the cluster.

Comment: @Tech Support I understand your question better now, so you are saying you have controlled access to the actual tables but were wanting to control access to the system tables. Unfortunately, my understanding is that as Redshift is a Postgres database all users have full access to the public schema. Therefore, even if a user does not have privledges to see a table they can still glean information from the metadata tables. I believe there is no way you can lock it down further than the methods stated in my answer.